# esb wso2 4.8.1 proxy service analysis soap xml error, the xml contain special char

Tags: api, proxy, wso2, esb, analysis

I have a sample,use api invoke proxy service, from the api transmission parameters contained in the special fields. then the proxy background parse error.

Sample API code:

```html
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="eva_data" context="/kdmService/rest/2.0/evaluation/data/current/kksCodes">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="kks=============" expression="$body/mediate/*[substring(name(),1,8)='kksCodes']"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="kks" expression="$body/mediate/*[substring(name(),1,8)='kksCodes']"></property>
         <header name="kksCodes" scope="transport" expression="get-property('kks')"></header>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:8280/services/searchMultiEvaData" format="pox"></address>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond></respond>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

request address:

```
http://localhost:8080/kdmService/rest/2.0/evaluation/data/current/kksCodes
```

request parameters:

```
kksCodes[]="EB001HP1MEJ01ME029BL01J1CB001BB01"
```

Sample proxy code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="searchMultiEvaData"
       transports="https,http,local"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="kksCode" expression="get-property('transport','kksCodes')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="uri.var.kksCodes"
                   expression="get-property('transport','kksCodes')"/>
         <property name="uri.var.isPathVariable" value="false"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint key="searchEvaKksAddressPoint"/>
         </call>
         <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="_payload"/>
         </enrich>
         <log>
            <property name="payload1" expression="get-property('_payload')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="payload" expression="get-property('_payload')"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

when api invoke proxy service,background error. console output error:

```html
[2016-04-15 11:34:47,144]  INFO - LogMediator To: /kdmService/rest/2.0/evaluation/data/current/kksC
odes, MessageID: urn:uuid:950bf641-c481-4527-8266-e535e906d6bf, Direction: request, kks============
= = EB001HP1MEJ01ME029BL01J1CB001BB01, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Env
elope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><mediate><kksCodes%5B%5
D>EB001HP1MEJ01ME029BL01J1CB001BB01</kksCodes%5B%5D></mediate></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2016-04-15 11:34:47,151] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,19
]
Message: 元素类型 "kksCodes" 必须后跟属性规范 ">" 或 "/>"。
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMElementImpl.java:670)
```

parameters xml format：

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
    <mediate>
     <kksCodes[]>EB001HP1MEJ01ME029BL01J1CB001BB01</kksCodes[]>
    </mediate>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think is kksCodes[] analysis error,but i don't know solve it. help me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the `<kksCodes[]>` element within a CDATA block as follows.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <mediate>
   <![CDATA[
     <kksCodes[]>EB001HP1MEJ01ME029BL01J1CB001BB01</kksCodes[]>
   ]]>
  </mediate>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Since the value within the CDATA block is not proper XML, you will not be able to extract the `kksCodes` using an xpath expression straight away.

To extract this you will have to perform a string manipulation using the script mediator in WSO2 ESB. [1]

Once the code is extracted you can set it as a property using the script mediator itself. 
Thereafter you can set the `kksCodes` as a transport header and pass it on to the proxy service.

Answer (score 0):

[String manipulation in WSO2 ESB using the script mediator](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/string-manipulation-in-wso2-esb-using-the-script-mediator) can easily be done by following this blog post. There is always the possibility to write your own custom mediator. This is a java program that gives you almost complete control but there are perhaps easier ways of getting the job done. IN this blog post example code how to do it.